# Including virtual environment in bash prompt

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

I am using bash on MacBook Air running macOS Mojave   and wanted to change the color of terminal prompt.

I was helped [on this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180624/how-to-change-font-color-of-text-in-vscode-integrated-terminal) and [this IBM blog](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) after which I used

```
export PS1="\[\e[30;47m\]\W\[\e[30;47m\]$\[\e[0m\]"
```

which has colour, wrapping, working directory and `$`.

It changed the colour but the prompt doesn't have `(base)` or `(ml)` in it. 
It is the virtual environment I created using conda. `conda deactivate`  removes it. Originally,

```
$ echo $PS1
(base) \h:\W \u\$           #original prompt with base.

$ conda deactivate          
$ echo $PS1
\h:\W \u\$                  #original prompt with no environment.  

$ conda activate ml
$ echo $PS1
(ml) \h:\W \u\$             #original prompt with ml environment. 

$ export PS1="\[\e[30;47m\]\W\[\e[30;47m\]$\[\e[0m\]"
$ echo $PS1
\[\e[30;47m\]\W\[\e[30;47m\]$\[\e[0m\]    #new prompt with no environment 
                                          #while ml is active
```

What can I include to have the `(base)` or `(ml)` there,  to make it like

```
$ echo $PS1
(base) \[\e[30;47m\]\W\[\e[30;47m\]$\[\e[0m\]    #expected result.
```

I didn't find any reference on [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) for virtual environment under controlling the prompt section.

I need to find where the current active environment is. Either in any file or any command that invokes the env name, which can written in ~/.bash_profile  and then add that variable to PS1.

Comment: Virtual environments aren't a bash thing, no wonder you won't find anything in the man page.

Comment: @nohillside Can I have the stored *variable* for the current active env in the bash_profile file somehow? and then add it to PS1?

Comment: Not sure what you want. Doesn't conda set that automatically once you activate/create an environment?

Comment: @nohillside But it is not in PS1 after modification. I want to see which env is active. See expected vs actual result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate a virtual environment for `conda` by running

```
conda activate base
```

Replace `base` with whatever (defined) conda environment you want to use.

```
pse@Mithos:~$ export PS1="\[\e[30;47m\]\W\[\e[30;47m\]$\[\e[0m\]"
~$cd .tmp
/Users/pse/.tmp
.tmp$conda activate base
((base) .tmp$conda deactivate 
.tmp$
```

Comment: Ah after activation, it does show the active env in the modified prompt too! Also just realised that by default, `base` is active, even after `conda deactivate`. I was just worried that I should not be working in a different one. Also, `conda info --envs` was helpful. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Comment: Can `conda info --envs` be run at terminal startup automatically? I want to know if ~/.bash_profile can do that or not.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Why shouldn't you be able to run it from .bash_profile?

Comment: because I didnt know it could be done. But now I do, tested this morning. :) Thanks