# How do I remove the source (base) from my terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix

I created some new aliases in my .bashrc file and did

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, everytime I open my terminal it always comes with the `(base)`

How do I remove that?

Comment: [Including virtual environment in bash prompt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367313/including-virtual-environment-in-bash-prompt) reverse problem

Comment: Related: [How do I prevent conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

Answer (score 53):

That's the "base" environment from Anaconda or Miniconda. It means the Python environment from `conda` is enabled by default.

There're two solutions.

1. Just [disable the base environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57974390/5101148), make sure your `conda >= 4.6`. Whenever you wanna use Python, enable an environment from `conda` manually with following command,

   ```sh
   # run this in an interactive shell
   # enable environment called "base", the default env from conda
   conda activate base
   # deactivate an environment
   conda deactivate
   ```
2. Enable the base environment, which is the default behavior of `conda`, but don't modify your prompt. Run the following command in an interactive shell once.

   ```sh
   conda config --set changeps1 false
   ```

Comment: Are you suggesting to add the two lines in point 1 in bashrc ?

Comment: @ankii Sorry, I didn't make it clear. The solution No.1 in the hyperlink should be set in .bashrc. The commands activate/deactivate an environment should be run in an interactive shell.

Comment: But every time one opens terminal, it would be annoying to enter these commands? I've added some lines in my bashrc profile as per this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367313/including-virtual-environment-in-bash-prompt For saving me the trouble. One such command(in my file) also brings up which git branch is active.

Comment: @ankii The solution one is to DISABLE activating the "base" environment, which means make the Python executable from "base" unavailable.

Answer (score 39):

If you'd prefer that conda's base environment not be activated on startup, you can always set the `auto_activate_base` parameter to false:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code in the .bashrc file should initialize an anaconda environment. Just remove them.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/proshore/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2$
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/proshore/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/proshore/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/proshore/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to the installation o Anaconda or Miniconda.
Depending on your mac version, you can just add one more line at the end of "~/.zshrc" or "~/.bashrc" with vim or any of your fav editors.

```
conda deactivate
```

Save the file, and now whenever you open the terminal again you won't see (base).