# Terminal automatically opens conda

Tags: terminal, bash, python

Every time I open my terminal I get

`(base) Users-MacBook-Air:~ Uriel$`

instead of

`Users-MacBook-Air:~ Uriel$`

without the *(base)* line which means that the environment of conda is open. In order to get this, I have to do

`conda deactivate`

every time in my Terminal and it is annoying because not only I always have to type that but also because every time I open it, I have to wait some seconds because I think is logging conda in

Up in my Terminal what I should only get is the label

`user--- -bash ---`

but before I get that I see that first appears

`Terminal --python<-bash`

then

`Terminal --java<-bash`

then

`Terminal --R<-bash`

etc., until I get the

`user--- -bash ---`.

Is it because I let conda open? Or something like that? How do I fix this?

Following is the contents of the `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
conda deactivate
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly share the contents of your `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile` files from your home directory.

Comment: @NimeshNeema could you vote for https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371727/how-do-i-remove-the-source-base-from-my-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1 please ? Just to link both in closure.

Comment: @NimeshNeema thanks for the editing. I am new at this. How do I share my `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `bash_profile`?

Comment: @turddisturb Run the following command in Terminal `pbcopy < ~/.bash_profile` and paste the content in your question. Repeat the command for all the files (you may or may not have some files on your computer). Mention the name of the file along with the contents.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I updated it. I ran the command ```open ~/.bashrc``` and ```open ~/.profile``` but it said that the files don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's default behaviour and it is not really problematic. If you deactivate it, the terminal will see default python installation, 2.7. That is troubling if you're using conda for python > 2.7.

If you're troubled by the `(base)` appearing in the prompt, Run:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

and add this line at the end

```
conda deactivate
```

- [How do I remove the source (base) from my terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371727/how-do-i-remove-the-source-base-from-my-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to get rid of (base) inside terminal app in 10.14.6?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376083/how-to-get-rid-of-base-inside-terminal-app-in-10-14-6)

Comment: Worked thanks. It still takes a few seconds because it still appears at the top or the terminal all the `Terminal --java<-bash`, `Terminal --R<-bash`,etc. Is this normal? Or it shouldn't happen?

Comment: see the linked questions, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371727/how-do-i-remove-the-source-base-from-my-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1 option 2

Comment: For the `Terminal --java<-bash` problems, follow Nimesh's instructions and update the question