# How to get rid of (base) inside terminal app in 10.14.6?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

when I get a fresh terminal, my prompt says

```bsh
(base) ~>
```

The (base) part is something that seems new.
Was this added during a recent update?
How do I get rid of it?
There is one piece of customization in my dot .profile, namely

```bsh
export PS1="\[\e[32;1m\]\w> \[\e[0m\]"
```

I also installed Conda recently, which might be related to that.

How do I remove  `(base)` ?

Comment: reverse problem: [Including virtual environment in bash prompt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367313/including-virtual-environment-in-bash-prompt)

Comment: @rydev see the edit history to see what more needed an edit. :) (except the bash lang indicator, that is fancy.) Drop by [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=apple.stackexchange.com) for further discussions. Also, OP: did you make a mistake about the macOS version there, or are you running [Tiger](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL387?locale=en_US) ?

Comment: @ankii: Yes, it is 10.14.6, not 10.4.6 as I originally typed. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a conda's environment indicator that none of the "new" environments is active, instead the default one is active. "new" here refers to those created by: `conda create --name NameOfEnv python=3.6` or similar.

For getting rid of it, add the line `conda deactivate` at the end of `~/.bash_profile`.

Verify by `conda info --envs`.

Comment: Dear @ankii this is pure genius, thanks very much!

Comment: To reload the profile: `source ~/.bash_profile` after change above.